# avoiding "which"

Tags: word-choice, word-order

I am trying to get rid of overused "it is" and "which" in my writing. This is one of improved sentences:

> Being a part of a popular TV program involves big **pressure hard to cope with for everyone**, especially a child.

Firstly, I feel unsure about the bold part, word order etc.

Secondly, do I need there "the" before "big pressure"? Surely, it would be redundant in such a case:

> Being a part of a popular TV program involves big pressure.

But when it gets specified by the "hard to cope..." part should i use "the"? I hope my doubts are understandable.

Comment: Why would you want to make a habit of removing _which_, particularly with a sentence like this that is rather confusing.

Comment: @ColinFine When I have to write an essay with 220-250 words I have to be careful about repetitions, but i am prone to make all sentences quite similar. Then it looks like "It is... which... Moreover, sth is... which...", so chances for max number of points are small.

Comment: I would say *pressure **that** is hard to cope with*. (But whether you use *which* or *that*, I think you should use one of them rather than just remove it.) Or you could say: *Being part of a TV program involves hard-to-cope-with pressure.*  But no matter how you phrase it, your addition of *especially a child* doesn't work. Nor does *with for everyone*.

Comment: big pressure is not great, by the way. undue pressure, great pressure,

Comment: @ziolek Others have explained why "which" is important. Some advice: if you're primarily worried about your word count, it would be more effective to use more specific verbs and nouns than to try to eliminate important syntax. Ex: Acting on a popular TV program is a high-pressure job, particularly for a child.

Answer (score 2):

It's OK to have a lot of "it is" and "which"/"that" in your writing. They're basic words with grammatical functions, so they appear a lot.

*pressure hard to cope with for everyone* is technically grammatical for at least some speakers, but it's unnatural, and it's so difficult to parse that even native speakers have trouble with it. So it's not a good idea to write like that. *pressure which is hard to cope with for everyone* is much better. You probably also want it to be nonrestrictive: *pressure, which is hard to cope with for everyone, especially a child*.

There shouldn't be a *the* before *big pressure*, because *pressure* is a mass noun used indefinitely, so it doesn't take an article.

One other problem: *pressure* doesn't have a size, so it can't be *big*. It should be *a lot of pressure* or *high pressure* or *great pressure* (which is slightly archaic).

Answer (score 0):

The sentence you have written is very hard to read without 'which is' or 'that is' after 'pressure'. There's really no way to get around that.

I wouldn't advise making a rule that you should omit every use of 'which' in your writing. Constructions like this are very common in the writing of most people. If you don't use them at all you run the risk of not sounding natural. Or even worse, you might write sentences that don't make sense. Your sentence above doesn't make good sense without 'which is' after 'pressure', for instance. The trick is figuring out what is the right frequency and placement of the word 'which' in your writing.

Many of the best writers edit their writing over and over, constantly looking for small improvements in word order, phrasing, word choice, etc. Instead of deleting the word 'which', try rewriting some of the sentences where it occurs. There is almost always more than one way to say the same thing. One very good editing technique is to write smaller sentences. This is a good way to get rid of extra conjunctions, like 'which'.

> Being a part of a popular TV program involves big pressure. This pressure can be hard to cope with for everyone, especially a child.

Here's another way to write it

> The big pressure involved with being a part of a popular TV program is hard to cope with for everyone, especially a child.

After you write your first draft, try rewriting half of your sentences that have 'which' in them and see whether you don't have a better essay than when you started.

Answer (score 0):

Being a part of a popular TV program involves big pressure hard to cope with for everyone, especially a child.

Being a part of a popular TV program creates major, hard-to-handle pressure on everyone, especially children.

Creativity is good.